# Open lightning component from Account new button

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, lightning-out

Since I cannot override NEW button with Lightning component what are my ways to open a lightning component on click of New Button of account?

I have tried lightning out in a visualforce, it works but the lightning events which are used to communicate between components in my Parent component doesn't get handled. Below is the code I wrote:

My VF:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="globalApp"></div>
    <script>
            $Lightning.use("c:GE_MDM_GlobalAppForSF1", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:GE_MDM_GlobalComponent",
                  {  },
                  "globalApp",
                  function(cmp) {
                      var eventAction = $A.get('e.c:GE_MDM_UIThemeDetected');
                      eventAction.setParams({
                          theme : 'SF1'
                      });
                        eventAction.fire();
                        console.log('fired');
                  });
            });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

GlobalAppForSF1App:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"  >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:GE_MDM_GlobalComponent"/>
</aura:application>
```

GE_MDM_GlobalComponent:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/GE_MDM_SLDS202/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css, /resource/MDM_Styles_New2/css/iids.css,/resource/GEMDMFlagIcons/font-awesome.min.css,/resource/GE_MDM_MasterCSS,/resource/MDM_Styles/css/mdm_design.css"/>

    <aura:handler event="c:toggleSpinner" action="{!c.toggleSpinner}"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:GE_MDM_UIThemeDetected" action="{!c.setDevice}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="device" type="String"/>


        <div class="slds">
            <br/>
            <c:GE_MDM_AccountSearchInputAndAppliedFilters />
            <c:GE_MDM_AccountFilters device="{!v.device}"/>
            <c:GE_MDM_AccountMDMSearchResult action="{!v.action}"/>
            <c:GE_MDM_UIDetectorComponent />
        </div>


    <!-- pop up components -->
    <c:GE_MDM_ViewSubscriptionDetails />
    <c:GE_MDM_ViewRelationship />
    <c:GE_MDM_ConfirmSelectAccount />


    <!-- spinner -->
    <center>
        <div class="slds-spinner_container toggle" style="position : fixed !important;" aura:id="spinner">
            <div class="slds-spinner slds-spinner--small" aria-hidden="false" role="alert">
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</aura:component>
```

The components get loaded but there are few lightning events which are used to communicate between child components in GlobalComponent. The lightning events get fired but doesn't reach the handler. Any idea what I am doing wrong or am I trying something impossible?

Comment: unless you post code it's going to be hard to answer anything .Question is likely to get close

Comment: I have added the code I wrote as of now. Could you please remove the on-hold tag and see if I am missing anything? I have referenced your blog while writing this code. http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2016/02/lightning-events-via-visualforce.html